# Kodi 19.3 - Segmentation fault (x00007fb4bc20c6c1 in pymalloc_alloc)

Tags: linux, fedora, kodi, segmentation-fault

I'm running **Linux Fedora 35**, **Kernel 5.15.10**, **Python 3.10.1.**

I installed **kodi 19.3** via the **DNF** package manager. However whenever I try to launch kodi it opens up so I can see the GUI, but then after about 3 seconds it always crashes.

Looking at the kodi crash log files under `/home/user/kodi_crashlog-xxxxxxxx.log` a segmentation fault occurs as follows near the top:

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f1989b826c1 in pymalloc_alloc (ctx=0x0, nbytes=64) at /usr/src/debug/python3.10-3.10.1-1.fc35.x86_64/Objects/obmalloc.c:1932
1932            if (UNLIKELY((pool->freeblock = *(block **)bp) == NULL)) {
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f1922ffd640 (LWP 3769))]
```

I have no idea why this is happening. The only thing I could think of was to reinstall kodi and remove any config files, but the problem persists.

Could it be something to do with the fact I'm using **Python 3.10.1?**

Here is the full crash log file: https://pastebin.com/sgM9ecKH

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Arch forums: until now only solution is downgrade (install package downgrade) to Python 3.9.9 and Kodi 19.3-1.

Don't forget to pin both if you downgrade manually (package downgrade does it for you).

Comment: Installing Python 3.9 alongside Python 3.10 seemed to work. Thanks.